# 2 LEFT JOINS count in a query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a download-component and want the categories to display the subcats and item count in advance. 1 of both works, but when trying to get both, the result is the multiply of both.

The code I use:

> SELECT a.*,
>    count(b.parentid) AS catscount,
>   count(c.id) AS itemscount
>   FROM (jos_foc_downl_categories AS a LEFT JOIN jos_foc_downl_items AS c ON c.catid = a.id )
>     LEFT JOIN jos_foc_downl_categories AS b ON b.parentid = a.id
>   WHERE a.parentid=0
>   GROUP BY a.id

This results for a category with 4 subcategories and 5 files in the number 20 for catscount and 20 for itemscount.

What's wrong with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're counting all rows, including duplicated values. Use DISTINCT to only count each distinct value once:

```
SELECT a.*,
count(DISTINCT b.parentid) AS catscount,
count(DISTINCT c.id) AS itemscount
....
```

Comment: I had to add one GROUP BY condition per count, but it worked. Thx